# Adding UWP option to Xamarin cross-platform application

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, uwp

I made a simple Xamarin cross-platform sqlite application for Android and IOS. I want to add Universal Windows Phone version too. To do that i followed [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/phone/) steps. I installed SQLite.Net-PCL from nuget manager. But i still need to write something for sqlite connection. In [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-xamarinforms-and-sqlite--cms-23020) link, at step 6 there is code for this but its for windows phone 8. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms supports database-driven applications using the SQLite database engine, which makes it possible to load and save objects in shared code.

Xamarin.Forms applications can use the SQLite.NET PCL NuGet package to incorporate database operations into shared code by referencing the SQLite classes that ship in the NuGet. Database operations can be defined in the Portable Class Library (PCL) project of the Xamarin.Forms solution, with platform-specific projects returning a path to where the database will be stored.

> But i still need to write something for sqlite connection. In this link, at step 6 there is code for this but its for windows phone 8. Can you please help me?

Windows 10 Universal Windows Platform (UWP)
Add the SQLite-net PCL NuGet to the UWP project by right-clicking and choosing Manage NuGet Packages.

Once the reference is added, implement the IFileHelper interface using the platform-specific Windows.Storage API to determine the data file path.

```
using Windows.Storage;
...

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(FileHelper))]
namespace Todo.UWP
{
    public class FileHelper : IFileHelper
    {
        public string GetLocalFilePath(string filename)
        {
            return Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Details please reference Xamarin.Forms [Local Databases](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/). The accompanying [sample application](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Todo/) is a simple Todo-list application.